# Hide "publish" button from dev server

Tags: lektor

My site is meant to be published by the continuous integration hook in my git server. The continuous integration script runs `lektor deploy`.

As such, I need the publish settings in my project file, but I don't like the peril of having an easily-acessible publish button that can be fat-fingered.

I don't see anything like that in the [command-line docs](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/cli/server/). Is that not possible?

Answer (score -2):

You should be using [`lektor build`](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/cli/build/) instead and serve your site with a proper http server. (or deploy remotely e.g. with [`lektor deploy`](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/cli/deploy/))

The dev server is meant to be just that, used for development. Running it in production might well be a security risk.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question. I'm not running it on production.

Comment: Then edit your question so it's clear what your problem is and what you're trying to accomplish. (and no, the edit after gratuitously -1ing my answer still doesn't make things clear.)